# What should I do when "error : Intel HAXM is not installed" is shown while running Emulator?

Tags: android-studio

Whenever I trying to run the emulator, an error shows up saying, "ERROR :x83 emulation currently requires hardware acceleration! Please ensure Intel HAXM is properly installed   and USABLE. "

Answer (score 0):

As per this response, the complete steps are:

1) Open SDK Manager (In Android Studio, go to Tools > Android > SDK Manager) and Download Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM installer) if you haven't.

2) Now go to your SDK directory

> C:\users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\extras\intel\Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager\ and run the file named intelhaxm-android.exe.
>   In case you get an error like "Intel virtualization technology (vt,vt-x) is not enabled". Go to your BIOS settings and enable Hardware Virtualization.

3) Restart Android Studio and then try to start the AVD again.

It might take a minute or 2 to show the emulator window.

Comment: Thank you so much, it was very helpful

Comment: @Subijoy mention not :)